# React: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, ecmascript-6, state

Im noob with React and trying to create a login form. When the user enters correct login informations a rest api will return JWT token. However i cant find how to set the state "token" to be the value of the response. Still i can save the response.token to localstorage and it shows correctly. I think the "this" points to wrong function, but how could i get around this without breaking the logic? Any hints? Thanks

Login.js

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

import Glyphicon from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Glyphicon';

import MyInput from './../components/Input';

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { Form } from 'formsy-react';

var server = "http://localhost:3000";

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            canSubmit: false,
            token: null
        };
        this.enableButton = this.enableButton.bind(this);
        this.disableButton = this.disableButton.bind(this);
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
    }

    submit(data) {
        axios.post(server + '/login', {
            username: data.username,
            password: data.password
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.token) {
                    var token = response.data.token;
                    localStorage.setItem("token", token);
                    this.setState({ token: token }); //Here is the problem
                    console.log(this.state.token);
                } else {
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
    }

    enableButton() {
        this.setState({ canSubmit: true })
    }
    disableButton() {
        this.setState({ canSubmit: false })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="loginForm">
                <h2 className="page-header">Login</h2>
                <Form onSubmit={this.submit} onValid={this.enableButton} onInvalid={this.disableButton}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Username: </label>
                        <MyInput name="username" validations="isExisty" validationError="Required" required />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password: </label>
                        <MyInput type="password" name="password" validations="isExisty" validationError="Required" required />
                    </div>
                    <button
                        type="submit"
                        className="btn btn-primary"
                        disabled={!this.state.canSubmit}>
                        Login
                    </button>
                </Form>
                <br/>
                <a href="register">Create user!</a>
                <a id="forgot" href="forgot">Forgot password?</a>

            </div>);
    }
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: In `.then` callback `this` does not refer to Component, use arrow function instead of `function` - `.then((response) => { ... })`. or set `this` for callback, ``.then(function (response) { ... }.bind(this))``

Comment: yes that was it. Thanks much!

Comment: It works for me. Thank you, - Alexander T.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use an arrow function to keep the context of `submit` and be able to access to `setState`:

```
submit(data) {
    axios.post(server + '/login', {
      username: data.username,
      password: data.password
    })
    .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.token) {
            var token = response.data.token;
            localStorage.setItem("token", token);
            this.setState({ token: token });
            console.log(this.state.token);
        } else {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this billion dollar answer! You should try and run for the President of the United States!! I've been millimeters away from setting my laptop on fire because of this stupid fix and you sir just saved me $1200 worth of my machine! Kudos.

Comment: Thank you for this help. Would love it if you could point to some docs that explain why using the arrow function keeps the original this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As Alexander stated in the comment, I must use the arrow function `=>` or set `this` for callback.